# django attribute error ------>AttributeError: module 'django.contrib.auth.views' has no attribute 'login', 'logout'

Tags: python, django

**AttributeError: module 'django.contrib.auth.views' has no attribute 'login', 'logout'**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from blog import views
from django.contrib.auth import views


urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'',include('blog.urls')),
url(r'accounts/login/$',views.login,name='login'),

url(r'accounts/logout/$',views.logout,name='logout',kwargs= 
{'next_page':'/'}),
]
```

Answer (score 1):

The function based views are deprecated, you need to use the class-based alternatives

```
url(r'accounts/login/$',views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
url(r'accounts/logout/$',views.LogoutView.as_view(next_page='/'), name='logout'),
```

You're also importing `views` twice the first import from `blog` is being overridden by the import from auth

Comment: Thank you so much!!problem solved!God bless you!! im a newbie!!